# Can we auto-correct Dijkstra?

Tags: discussion, edits, spelling

I keep coming across questions and answers, some highly upvoted, where Dijkstra is spelled Djikstra. Is there an automated spell-check or auto-correct feature on SE that would allow to fix all these errors in one go? There are just too many to do it manually, and surely Dijkstra deserves to have his name spelled correctly.

---

To be clear: I'm asking whether there is some kind of automated process that could be run once; I'm not suggesting to keep this switched on permanently.

Comment: Perhaps they are highly upvoted because searchers also misspelled his name and found those posts.  We should be careful about automagically fixing them.

Comment: Doing a simple search I only found 294 posts with "Djikstra". What query did you use?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I tried a few search engines and they all correctly found "Dijkstra's algorithm" when I searched for "Djikstra's algorithm". (My computer's spell checker also just highlighted the misspelling.) I'm not sure having the misspelled names is attracting many more hits.

Comment: @beaker I meant too many for me to fix in my limited and valuable time. Besides, such targeted editing sprees seem to be discouraged; we're supposed to fix things as we come across them.

Comment: @m69 Oh, I was thinking multiple people working on it. Certainly didn't mean to imply that you (or anyone) should take it on alone. Just wondering if I missed something in my search.

Answer (score 16):

I respect Edsger Dijkstra as much as the next developer, but I'm not convinced that his name should be a special case for autocorrection. Two arguments come to my mind here. The more obvious one (I think) is "we don't do it for anything else." The better one is "we already allow and encourage community editing."

If we implement this as an automated thing, then what else should we correct automatically? All those decisions take time and effort to make that distract from Q&A and Documentation (let's face it, if you're coming here *just* for meta, you're kinda doing it wrong... not that that's ever described me...). And once decided upon, there's development, performance and maintenance cost to those features.

Seems better to just use the community editing practices we already have in place to slowly tackle these. It is *incredibly* rare for a post to have exactly one error or place that could be improved with editing. Generally speaking, editors should be correcting everything they are capable of fixing when they submit edits, not just fixing one problem and leaving others. Humans would be able to make multiple improvements along with fixing misspellings of "Dijkstra"; machine autocorrection would not. (Really, the lack of a strong editing culture on the site is more of a root problem here, and what you're pointing out is merely a symptom, but that's a way bigger issue than what your question was trying to address.)

I might be slightly more receptive to this if the misspelling were actively interfering with communication, but I don't think people are getting confused about the intended meaning of the misspelled word "Djikstra" (or any other variants).

Comment: I was using the term auto-correct to mean some kind of automated process; I'm not proposing to keep this switched on all the time.